# How can I setup paths for Xcode bots

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration

Our game has the following directory structure:

```
 + AwesomeGame
   + GameSrc *(this an SVN repo)*
      - GameSrc.xcodeproj
      - [... all the other source and data]
   + FrameworkSrc *(this is another SVN repo)*
      - Framework.xcodeproj
      - [... framework source code]
```

The framework project is used in multiple projects, each game is individual but follows the same directory structure. The GameSrc.xcodeproj includes Framework.xcodeproj, and has its targets setup as dependancies.

Inside the GameSrc.xcodeproj we have a Header Search Path set to..

```
"${PROJECT_DIR}/../FrameworkSrc/"
```

.. so the Game can find the headers for the framework when building. This is works well and has for some time.

Now I want to start utilising the Continuous Integration features in Xcode 5 and OSX server. The bot is smart enough to spot the dependancies and checkout both projects. The problem however is that it doesn't checkout the projects to our folder structure, so builds will not work.

According to the logs it checks out the projects with these folder names:

```
http_ourserver_svn_GameSrc/
http_ourserver_svn_FrameworkSrc/
```

To solve this it would be great if there was a way to define how a bot checks out repositories, or if there was someway to change my search paths to reference included projects.

Does anyone know of a way to get this to work?

Comment: did you resolve this? I have the same issue

Comment: I'm going to try something using symlinks, I'll post an answer if I get anywhere

Comment: @DannyParker No luck?

Comment: Not had much time to look into this, and the build machine I was using was procured for something else. However, it seems like an update made this problem go away. I can't confirm that unfortunately.

Comment: Did you every figure this out? I think I've got a similar issue with submodules that are Cocoa Frameworks. Xcode server is checking them all out but doesn't build them in the right places, so when it tries to copy/link them to the main project, it fails.

Comment: It seems the bot system doesn't give any control over where things are checked out, or from what branches (It sticks to the branch that the bot was created under). It seems they are just not suitable for multi-repo development. The latest version does allow a user to run a script as part of the build so there might be something that can be done there to symlink some folders back into place.